# Transpose and stacking levels in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, stack, pivot

I am facing an issue with properly transposing and stacking multi-level columns in pandas dataframe.

Here's my initial dataset:

```
1990                      1991     
Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4        Q1     Q2     Q3     Q4
A | B  A | B  A | B  A | B     A | B  A | B  A | B  A | B
```

I want to convert this multi-level columns (3 levels) into single column (flatten it basically).

Here's my expected output:

```
   Year   Quarter  A   B
   1990   Q1       a1  b1
          Q2       a2  b2
   ....   ...      ... ...
   1991 ..................
```

Below is the my code that I tried but it fails (output is not as expected).

```
df.transpose().stack(level=0).to_frame().reset_index()
```

This expands `Year`, `Quarter` as expected but fails to properly align the remaining two columns of `A` and `B`.

Am I missing any stacking, unstacking or pivoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check with `stack` with two levels

```
df.stack([0,1]).reset_index()
```

---

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=idx,index=[1]).fillna(0)
df.stack([0,1])
           a  b
1 1900 q1  0  0
       q2  0  0
       q3  0  0
       q4  0  0
  1991 q1  0  0
       q2  0  0
       q3  0  0
       q4  0  0
```

Comment: Works like charm! Not sure how did I miss stacking at two levels? Thanks man! :)

Comment: @sgokhales yw :-)